# Getting error 91 while running the data scraping code

Tags: excel, runtime-error, screen-scraping, vba

I'm getting an error when I call: `Datascrape()` which is defined as:

```
Sub Datascrape()
  Dim count, i As Long
  Dim ie As Object
  count = Sheets("properties-2017-06-05").Cells(1, 10).Value
  Sheets("properties-2017-06-05").Range("D7:E" & count).ClearContents
  For i = 7 To count
    Set ie = CreateObject("internetexplorer.Application")
    ie.navigate Sheets("properties-2017-06-05").Cells(i, 3).Value
    While ie.busy
      DoEvents
    Wend
    'ie.Visible = True
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:03"))
    Sheets("properties-2017-06-05").Cells(i, 4) = 
    'error happens here
    ie.document.getelementsbyclassname("col-xs-12 viewAllReviews")(0).innertext
    On Error Resume Next
    Sheets("properties-2017-06-05").Cells(i, 5) = 
    ie.document.getelementsbyclassname("APGWBigDialChart widget")(0).getElementsByTagName("text")(1).innertext
    On Error Resume Next
    ie.Quit
  Next
End Sub
```

After about 3 or 4 iterations of the loop, it throws an `Error 91` and I do not understand why.

[link to picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4shW.png)

Comment: For starters, you should not be creating IE *inside* the loop.  `Application.Wait` is at best an unreliable method for (presumably) waiting for web page to load. Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: I need to navigate through different urls actually. If i do not create ie object inside then i am getting run time error,

Answer (score 0):

The runtime error 91 will happen when the object evaluates to `Nothing`, because you're chaining `(0)` (index)against an expression that might not return a valid object/collection.

Using this expression,

```
ie.document.getelementsbyclassname("col-xs-12 viewAllReviews")(0).innertext
```

If the `getElementsByClassName` method returns an empty collection, then attempting to index that collection `0` will raise a 91 error.

Essentially, your code is written in such a way that assumes this method call will *always* result in a collection of length >= 1.

Why not?

Your waiting loop and `Application.Wait` may not be adequate. Consider modifying the waiting loop:

```
While ie.busy and not ie.ReadyState = 4
    DoEvents
Wend
```

That *might* be enough to fix the problem. I would also suggest moving the `ie` instantiation *outside* of the loop, there is no reason to repeatedly create the `ie` object inside the loop.

*This* will certainly *avoid* the error, and suggest what/where to debug:

```
Sub Datascrape()
Dim count as Long, i As Long
Dim ie As Object
Dim ws as Worksheet

Set ws = Sheets("properties-2017-06-05")
Set ie = CreateObject("internetexplorer.Application")

count = ws.Cells(1, 10).Value
ws.Range("D7:E" & count).ClearContents
For i = 7 To count
    ie.navigate ws.Cells(i, 3).Value
    While ie.busy and not ie.ReadyState = 4
        DoEvents
    Wend
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:03"))  '## This line probably isn't needed
    Dim ele
    Set ele = ie.document.getelementsbyclassname("col-xs-12 viewAllReviews")
    If ele Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Class name 'col-xs-12 viewAllReviews' isn't found!"
        ws.Cells(i, 4) = "NOT FOUND"  '## Breakpoint here if needed to debug
    Else:
        ws.Cells(i, 4) = ele(0).innerText
    End If
    On Error Resume Next
    ws.Cells(i, 5) = _
        ie.document.getelementsbyclassname("APGWBigDialChart widget")(0).getElementsByTagName("text")(1).innertext
    On Error GoTo 0
Next
ie.Quit
End Sub
```

## NOTE: In order to provide more specific guidance, you would need to provide example input that will help reproduce the error.

## Also, a note on your error-handling

You have `On Error Resume Next` then an expression, followed by `On Error Resume Next`, inside your loop. This is almost certainly not what you intend. Normally, it is like:

```
On Error Resume Next
 << expression(s) >>
On Error GoTo 0
```

Whereas you have:

```
On Error Resume Next
 << expression(s) >>
On Error Resume Next
```

Unless you actually have the former, it seems like your loop cannot *possibly* raise an error except on the *very first* iteration. `GoTo 0` resumes normal error handling, `Resume Next` simply means "Pretend errors aren't happening, even if they are". It provides no diagnostic information that can be used to troubleshoot. As a rule of thumb, this is to be avoided (with few exceptions). What you've done is to essentially allow an error on iteration 1, but suppress all other errors.

Comment: what line raises the error? and can you provide example input?

Comment: I am still getting the error 91 after running your code.
I am still getting the error 91 after running your code.
Dim ele
    ele = ie.document.getelementsbyclassname("col-xs-12 viewAllReviews")
    If ele.length = 0 Then' error 91 happened here.
        ws.Cells(i, 4) = "NOT FOUND"  '## Breakpoint here if needed to debug

Comment: apartmentratings.com/fl/davie/palm-ranch-apartments_9199332346275159825/
I need to list down the reviews and overall rating from different properties like the one mentioned in the url.

Comment: I made a small revision it should be `Set ele = ... ` and also probably `If ele is Nothing...` but I haven't tested it and won't be able to until Monday probably.